# How can I use RandomFunction to solve an SDE in reverse time?

Tags: differential-equations, random, stochastic-calculus, random-process

I am working with a problem of the Ito-stochastic differential form given by
$$\mathrm{d}x=g(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t+f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}W,$$
where $W$ is a Wiener process.
I furthermore have to satisfy the condition
$$x(t_f)=x_f,$$
where $x_f$ is a constant vector and $t_f$ is the final integration time.

How can I use Mathematica built-in functions to solve this in reverse from $t=t_f$ to $t=0$, such as with `RandomFunction`?

Comment: `BrownianBridgeProcess` lets you pin the process at the ends. Depending on your $g$ and $f$, you might be able to represent the solution in the form of a bridge, or transformed bridge process.

Comment: @flinty thanks. Idk if that will work, but Ill look into that.